# Using the axiom of choice to choose bijections

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I couldn't think of a better question title. I am trying to understand the proof of theorem 1.8 in [this](http://www.math.unt.edu/~moliver/fa04s/JacksonNotes/card.pdf) introduction to cardinals.

> **Theorem 1.8.** Let $\kappa\in CARD$. Let $X=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}X_\alpha$, where $|X_\alpha|\leq\kappa$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$. Then $|X|\leq \kappa$.
>   Proof. Using AC, let $f$ be a function with domain $\kappa$ such that for all $\alpha<\kappa$, $f(\alpha):\kappa\to X_\alpha$ is a bijection. Define $F:\kappa\times\kappa\to X$ by $F(\alpha,\beta)=f(\alpha)(\beta)$. Clearly $F$ is onto, and the result follows by lemma 1.7. [which says $\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$]

How can we "use AC" to obtain $f$? Is $f$ the choice function? Shouldn't it map each $\alpha$ to a member of $\alpha$?

Also, how can we possibly ensure there is such a bijection for each $\alpha$ – we only know $|X_\alpha|\leq \kappa$, ie $|X_\alpha|<\kappa$ is possible! In that case how can there be a bijection?

Comment: I added the tag [tag:axiom-of-choice]. It's one of the more useful tags, since it's almost sure to draw Asaf's immediate attention to the question :-)

Comment: That sounds like a powerful tool indeed! I'll use it to summon him in case of emergency. x_^

Comment: @joriki: It usually works better when I'm not in a seminar room, and right in the middle of a discussion with the speaker. But yes, generally that would be a valid method. :P

Comment: How is this out of scope? I've read a paper and I struggle to understand some of proofs so I come to StackExchange ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that we only need $f(\alpha)\colon \kappa\to X_\alpha$ to be *onto* (after all the final $F$ is also only needed onto). So I suppose "bijection" is just a typo.

We are given for each $\alpha$ that $|X_\alpha|\le\kappa$, i.e., that the set $S_\alpha$ of surjective maps $\kappa\to X_\alpha$ is $\ne\emptyset$. We use AC to pick an element $f(\alpha)\in S_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.