# Does the regularity of $\omega_{\alpha+1}$ need Axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Many books indicate yes to this question. However, I found the only lemma they claim to use AC is the following statement:

If $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets, then $|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i|\leq|I|\sup_{i\in I}|A_i|$.

But if we replace this statement by the following version, then this does not require AC anymore.

If $\{\beta_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\gamma}$ is a sequence of ordinals, then $|\sup_{\alpha<\gamma}\beta_\alpha|\leq|\gamma|\sup_{\alpha<\gamma}|\beta_\alpha|$.

**Proof**: We map $\delta$ to the least $\alpha$ such that $\delta<\beta_\alpha$ together with the image of $\delta$ under the map $f:\beta_\alpha\to|\beta_\alpha|\to\sup_{\alpha<\gamma}|\beta_\alpha|$, i.e., $\delta\mapsto(\alpha,f(\delta))$.

This statement is used to prove:

For infinite $\kappa$, $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$ is the least cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\kappa=\sum_{\beta<\lambda}\kappa_\beta$, where $\kappa_\beta<\kappa$.

**Proof**:

($\leq$) Let $\kappa=\sum_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha$, where $\kappa_\alpha<\kappa$. We may assume $\kappa_\alpha\geq 1$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$. Then either $\lambda$ or one of $\kappa_\alpha$ is infinite. So $\kappa=\lambda\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha$. If $\kappa=\lambda$, then $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)\leq\lambda$. If $\kappa=\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\kappa_\alpha$, then we have a cofinal sequence, so $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)\leq\lambda$ in this case as well.

($\geq$) Let $f:\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)\to\kappa$ be a cofinal sequence and write $\lambda=\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$. We may assume $f$ is nonzero. Then we see $\kappa=|\kappa|=|\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}f(\alpha)|\leq\lambda\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}|f(\alpha)|\leq\kappa$. And since $\lambda\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}|f(\alpha)|=\sum_{\alpha<\lambda}|f(\alpha)|$, we got the equality $\kappa=\sum_{\alpha<\lambda}|f(\alpha)|$.

Then the proof goes:

If $\omega_{\alpha+1}$ were singular, then $\lambda=\mathrm{cf}(\omega_{\alpha+1})\leq\omega_\alpha$. Write $\omega_{\alpha+1}=\sum_{\beta<\lambda}\kappa_\beta$, where $\kappa_\beta\leq\omega_\alpha$. Hence, $\omega_{\alpha+1}=\sum_{\beta<\lambda}\kappa_\beta\leq\sum_{\omega_\alpha}\omega_\alpha=\omega_\alpha^2=\omega_\alpha$, contradiction.

Maybe I made a mistake somewhere, I don't know. Could anyone identify where is AC hiding in this proof? Thanks!

Disclaimer: all cardinals are well-orderable ordinals.

Comment: My impression is if you want to convince people your question is not a duplicate, you reference the questions it might duplicate and explain how your question is different and the answers to the other questions fail to answer your question. This provides *evidence* that you've considered possible duplicate questions, and it helps answerers know what it is you are and are not looking for.

Comment: The linked question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758211/for-every-cardinal-kappa-kappa-is-regular (given by the one who flagged duplicate) which is about the understanding the proof, NOT about the usage of axiom of choice. He also uses a different proof. However, there is another link given by the first answer to the linked question, but from what I read, AC is necessary in order to prove this fact, but that post is again NOT indicating where AC is used in the proof, but rather why it SHOULD be necessary (it is consistent with ZF that omega1 has countable cofinality.)

Comment: The statement you mentioned as not requiring choice if the $A_i$ are well-orderable actually uses choice even in that case. There are models where the inequality fails with $I=\omega$, each $A_i$ a countable subset of $\omega_1$, and $\bigcup_i A_i=\omega_1$.

Comment: (Also: Stop the yelling.)

Comment: Perhaps your question is really about where it is that choice is used in the standard proof of the statement $|\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i|\le|I|\sup_{i\in I}|A_i|$, when the $A_i$ and $I$ are well-ordered (not just well-orderable!). If that's the case, then you should change your question and ask that explicitly. If you do this, make it clear that you actually know the proof (write it down), and indicate as explicitly as possible how you circumvent choice at each step. Then indicate that you are aware that you made a mistake, and would like to understand where.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was angry because my question was closed by someone in freaking 5 minutes! no reason was given, not a single comment. Clearly this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo, I added a new version of that statement and proofs of it. The AC is still hiding somewhere.

Comment: Ok. In the proof of the new version of the statement, you have that for each $\alpha $ there is an injection from $\beta_\alpha $ into $|\beta_\alpha |$, trivially, but you are using something else, namely that there is a function that for each $\alpha $ gives you such an injection. How do you get such a function? (And, do you see that this is really what you are using, and that it is not the same as the trivial fact that each ordinal injects in its cardinality?)

Comment: Have you also looked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758197/using-the-axiom-of-choice-to-choose-bijections?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Thanks for your answer. So does that mean the characterization of cf($\kappa$) as a sum requires AC as well? Can AC be avoided somehow in the proof?

Comment: (By the way, the correct way to argue that your question is not a duplicate is to clarify the closed question and explain why you disagree with the closure; not delete and subsequently re-post it.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila By the way, go ahead and close everyone's question except yours. If you think you are so good that you can close others' question as you wish, why NOT answering them first?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Also, since you don't contribute anything useful to my question, please STOP posting on this comment section and do your daily job of closing others' questions. Thanks!

Comment: If a question get closed, NO ONE can answer that question any more. And there is no rule against posting the question again. So please stop trying on closing my questions again, thanks! If you simply don't like my question or don't want to answer them, fine, just LEAVE THEM ALONE. I appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: @Kaa1el There is a rule against posting the question again. We even have a message template for that. The correct way is, as Asaf pointed out, to edit the original question to make clear why it's not a duplicate, then it will be reopened if the argument is convincing. If things don't work out, turn to [meta].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a hidden assumption in the proof of your first proposition. If  $\beta_{x}\leq d<d'<\beta_{\alpha}$ whenever $x<\alpha ,$ then in order that the map that sends $d$ to $(\alpha,f_{\alpha}(d))$ be 1-to-1, you need each$f_{\alpha}:\beta_{\alpha}\to |\beta_{\alpha}|$ to be 1-to-1. Now for each $\alpha$, such $f_{\alpha}$ exists but it is generally  not unique, so we cannot apply the Replacement Axiom to assert  the existence of the sequence $(f_{\alpha})_{\alpha < \beta}.$ This is where AC is hiding.

Even when trying to prove in ZF  that $\omega_1$ is regular, we hit this difficulty when we try to show in ZF that a countable union of countable ordinals is countable.

I dk whether there has been any progress on the open problem of whether it can be shown in ZF that a regular uncountable cardinal exists.

Comment: The question in your last paragraph was solved negatively by Moti Gitik in [MR0576462 (81h:03096)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=576462). [*All uncountable cardinals can be singular*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760939), Israel J. Math. **35** (1980), no. 1-2, 61–88.

Comment: The precise consistency strength of $\mathsf{ZF}$+``all uncountable cardinals are singular'' is still open, though.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does that mean the characterization of cf($\kappa$) as a sum requires AC as well? Can AC be avoided somehow in the proof?

Comment: If I understand you, we can, in ZF, define $cf(k)$ as the least $m\in ON $ such that  $k=\sum_{a\in m}f(a)$ for some $f:m\to k.$  See the above comments. Proving in ZF that $\omega_1$ is regular would prove that a measurable cardinal doen't exist, which I think wold be quite a shock, and might win you a Fields medal.